# Drawing fastest route between two points

Tags: mapbox, turf

In reference at this example https://gist.github.com/miccferr/f0716649c82e5cefc5eb
i'm trying to visualize the fastest route between two points. 
After i drag the position marker I would like to click on a fixed marker and then draw a stroke between them but i'm having a problem.

This is how i modify the code in the above link:

```
    L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6IlhHVkZmaW8ifQ.hAMX5hSW-QnTeRCMAy9A8Q';

var map = L.map('map').setView([44.4948,11.3441],  16);
// Attribution Link
mapLink ='<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
L.tileLayer(
    'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors',
        maxZoom: 18,
    }).addTo(map);
// definiamo dei layer vuoti
var bufferLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer();
var nearest_fc = L.mapbox.featureLayer();
var pathLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer();


// creo un marker
var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng( 44.49528086931113,11.347181797027588), {
    icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
        'marker-color': 'ff8888',
        'marker-symbol':'pitch'

    }),
    draggable:'true'
});

 // carico i dati
var rastrelliere = omnivore.kml('data/rastrelliere.kml').addTo(map);

// Buffer dinamico attorno al marker
function pointBuffer (pt, radius, units, resolution) {
var ring = []
var resMultiple = 360/resolution;
for(var i  = 0; i < resolution; i++) {
  var spoke = turf.destination(pt, radius, i*resMultiple, units);
  ring.push(spoke.geometry.coordinates);
 }
if((ring[0][0] !== ring[ring.length-1][0]) && (ring[0][1] != ring[ring.length-1][1])) {
  ring.push([ring[0][0], ring[0][1]]);
}
return turf.polygon([ring])
}



// ****Get position, draw buffer, find within, find nearest, add to map****

function updateVenues(fc,md){
// converto in GeoJSON il livello
fc= fc.toGeoJSON()

// creo un oggetto turf con la posizione
var point=turf.point([md.lng, md.lat]);

// calcolo un buffer attorno al punto
var  buffer = pointBuffer(point, 1, 'kilometers', 120);
buffer.properties = {
  "fill": "#00704A",
  "fill-opacity":0.1,
  "stroke": "#00704A",
  "stroke-width": 2,
  "stroke-opacity": 0.5
};
// creo il livello con il buffer
bufferLayer.setGeoJSON(buffer);

// filtro le features (rastrelliere delle biciclette)
var within = turf.featurecollection(fc.features.filter(function (shop){
  if (turf.distance(shop, point, 'kilometers') <= 1) return true;
}) 
);

// coloro le features
within.features.forEach(function(feature){
  feature.properties["marker-color"] = "C73E3E";
  feature.properties["title"] = '<br>'+feature.properties["name"]+'<br>Bikes: '+feature.properties["nbBikes"]+'<br>Empty Docks: '+feature.properties["nbEmptyDocks"];
  feature.properties["marker-size"] = "small";
  feature.properties["marker-symbol"] = "bicycle";
});

// calcolo la feature più vicina
nearest = turf.nearest(point, within);
// coloro la feature più vicina
nearest.properties["marker-color"] = "3ad78d";
nearest.properties["title"] = '<br>'+nearest.properties["name"]+'<br>Bikes: '+nearest.properties["nbBikes"]+'<br>Empty Docks: '+nearest.properties["nbEmptyDocks"];
nearest.properties["marker-size"] = "large";
nearest.properties["marker-symbol"] = "bicycle";

// creo un unica collezione di feature colorate (la più vicina + le rimanenti)
nearest_fc.setGeoJSON(turf.featurecollection([within, nearest])).addTo(map);
```

Starting to modify updateVenues()

```
nearest_fc
    .on('mouseover', function(e) {
        e.layer.openPopup();
    })
    .on('mouseout', function(e) {
        e.layer.closePopup();
    })
    .on('click', function(e){

        console.log(e);

    // query for directions and draw the path
        var directionsAPI = 'http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/directions/mapbox.walking/'+md.lng+','+md.lat+';'+e.latlng.lng+','+e.latlng.lat+'.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6IlhHVkZmaW8ifQ.hAMX5hSW-QnTeRCMAy9A8Q';
        console.log(md);


        $.get(directionsAPI, function(data){

          console.log("apiData: " + data);
            var coords= data.routes[0].geometry.coordinates;

            coords.unshift([md.lng, md.lat]);
            coords.push([e.latlng.lng, e.latlng.lat]);

            var path = turf.linestring(coords, {
                "stroke": "#00704A",
                "stroke-width": 4,
                "opacity":1
            });

            window.setTimeout(function(){

            pathLayer.setGeoJSON(path).addTo(map);


            },400);

        })
    });
};

// Funzione per gestire l'evento 'clicca' sul bottone 'Filtra' 
$('#attiva-filtro').click(function () {
if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
  $(this).removeClass('active');
  map.removeLayer(marker);
  map.removeLayer(bufferLayer);
  map.removeLayer(nearest_fc);
  rastrelliere.addTo(map);
  map.removeLayer(pathLayer);

}else{
  $(this).addClass('active');
  marker.addTo(map);
  updateVenues(rastrelliere,marker._latlng);
  bufferLayer.addTo(map);
  map.removeLayer(rastrelliere);

}
});

// ogni volta che muovo il marker lancio la funzione per calcolare/colorare ecc...
marker.on('dragstart', function(){ 
map.removeLayer(pathLayer);
});
```

at this point in dragend event i get the new cordinates of the position marker

```
marker.on('dragend', function(){ 

var m = marker.getLatLng();

updateVenues(rastrelliere,m);

});
```

It work until I do not drag the position marker,
after dragging it in a new position the whole of the "updateVenues" function work properly apart when i call the onclick event in "nearest_fc" layer.
During this event, the coordinates of the position marker are setted two times,
dragging again the marker they are setted three times (original position,second position after the first dragging and third position after second dragging) and so on, i can not understand.. any idea?